# How to stop macOS from asking if I want to set a default browser?

Tags: macos, defaults

Is there a mechanism I could disable to get rid of the dialog every time I run a new browser on macOS?

[image: dialog]

Comment: When does that pop up - after starting an app? If so which one?

Comment: Never seen anything like that, except **from** a browser. Not sure this is a macOS dialog, possibly comes from Opera.

Comment: I run three different browsers concurrently and I think I have only seen that message once... Using Safari, Chrome and Firefox . And I'm switching between them or restarting them 5 or more times a day...

Comment: You were right guys. This is not the system that triggers the dialog - it's the browser.

Comment: Chrome triggers this on each launch and there seems to be no way of stopping it.

Answer (score 2):

For Opera (and possibly for all Chromium-based browsers) it's enough to run the binary with `--no-default-browser-check` flag.